# Multiplication operator overload modifying original variable (C#)?

Tags: c#, types, reference, operators

I'm working on a matrices library as a learning project, and in doing so I've overloaded the * operator to perform matrix multiplication. I've also overloaded it to handle scalar multiplication (multiplying every element of the matrix by a double). My problem is that when the following code is run, both test2 and test are being modified, which is undesired.

```
Matrix test2 = 2 * test;
```

I'm sure this is a problem with the fact that Matrix is a class, and is therefore being passed by reference, but without changing Matrix to a struct (something I don't think will be suitable, and when tried doesn't seem to work), I can't see any way of resolving this. How would I fix this?

The actual operator code is

```
public static Matrix operator *(Matrix m1, double c)
{
   Matrix ret = m1;

   for (long i = 0; i < ret.Width; i++) // Iterate over the rows.
    {
        for (long p = 0; p < ret.Height; p++) // Iterate over the columns.
        {
            ret[i, p] *= c;
        }
    }

   return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't be modifying the existing matrix with your code. The signature *screams* that it is creating a *new* `Matrix` and returning it.

I'm not positive what your copy method/constructor is, but *don't* assign `m1` to `ret`; you should be making a *copy* of `m1`, modifying the *copy*, and returning the *copy*, leaving `m1` *unchanged*.

```
public static Matrix operator *(Matrix m1, double c)
{
    Matrix ret = m1.Clone(); //not sure what your "copy" method is

    //do the multiplication on ret

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: I've now created a method for doing this, but is there any way to avoid calling xxxx.Clone() every time the value needs to be copied? I.E. when using ret = m1; have that equivalent to ret = m1.Clone();

Comment: The only way would be to implement your `Matrix` as a value-type `struct`. That might have implications for how you're currently using the type though. (google "mutable structs are evil")

Answer (score 1):

Since `Matrix` is a reference type, `ret = m1` does not make a copy of your input argument and you end up modifying it.

The proper solution to this problem would be to make a deep copy of `m1` and modify that. Something like:

```
Matrix ret = m1.MakeCopy(); // you need to define this

// and now you are free to modify ret as much as you like
```